# Why is the focus request not working in this code?

Tags: java, swing, focus

I am trying to stablish the focus in the label "test", but it remains on the item "play".

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
  public GamePanel() {
    super();
    addItem("play",new ActionPlay());
    addItem("setings",new ActionSetings());
    addItem("exit",new ActionExit());
    JLabel label=new JLabel("test");
    label.setFocusable(true);
    add(label);
    label.requestFocus();
  }

  public void addItem(String name, AbstractAction action) {
    add(new Item(name, action));
  }
}
```

Any ideas on why is this happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the [`Component#requestFocus()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocus--) Javadoc: "_This component must be displayable, focusable, visible and all of its ancestors (with the exception of the top-level Window) must be visible for the request to be granted._" - So, are your components already visible? We can't tell since you didn't provide a [mre]. Also, the Javadoc also notes that: "_Because the focus behavior of this method is platform-dependent, developers are strongly encouraged to use requestFocusInWindow when possible._"

Comment: I addition to the sage advice of @maloomeister, note that the panel will not be displayed until some time after the constructor is called and that a request to gain focus will *always* fail if a component is not currently displayed.

Comment: Why would you set focus on a JLabel? By default it is set unfocusable for a reason. Users expect a component to have focus only if you can somehow interact with the component. If you really need to set focus on some other component before it is added to the frame then check out the `RequestFocusListener` found in [Dialog Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/)